# Python reverse function

Tags: python

Write the definition of a function, is_reverse , whose two parameters are arrays of integers of equal size. The function returns true if and only if one array is the reverse of the other. ("Reverse" here means  same elements but in reverse order.)

This is what I have so far:

```
def is_reverse(a,b):
    c = b.reverse()
    for i in len(a):
        if a[i] == c[i]:
            return True
        if a[i] != c[i]:
            return False
```

Comment: Im guessing it doesnt work ... cause his logic is wrong ...

Comment: I know it doesn't work, I was hoping he would realize this isn't a question haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code unconditionally exits after the first time in the loop (either the characters are the same, or they're different and you have a return statement for both cases).  You only want to return `True` after you've checked all the string elements.

There's also another slight catch -- `list.reverse()` reverses the list *in place*.  This means that `c = b.reverse()` changes `b` and sets `c` to `None`.  I've modified that in my code below.

```
def is_reverse(a,b):
    # copy b -- Not strictly necessary if you don't care about changing the inputs...
    c = b[:] 
    c.reverse()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] != c[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

Others have pointed out that there are more idiomatic ways to go about doing this:

```
a == b[::-1]
```

is the classic example (it does the loop for you!).  But I left the structure of the original code as much intact as I could to hopefully make it more clear how python works.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for using my code!

Answer (score 6):

It can be written on one line with

```
 def is_reverse(a, b): return a == b[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid making a copy of either list:

```
len(a) == len(b) and all(itertools.imap(operator.eq, a, reversed(b)))
```

If you're using Python3 then there's no `itertools.imap`, because the builtin `map` no longer copies.